# I am trying to get a banner to display random ads when a page loads with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment to get a banner to display a random image with JavaScript. My functions `randInt()`, `adDescription()` and `adLink()` were provided for me. I basically just have to call on these functions to display the random ad. I have created a script in the  element with the id of 'value maps'. I can not get the images to display, the img src code. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on HTML and XHTML 5th Edition
   Tutorial 10
   Case Problem 2

   The Ridgewood Herald Tribune
   Author: Collin Klopstein  
   Date: November 15, 2013   

   Filename:         front.htm
   Supporting files: ads1.jpg - ads5.jpg, ads.js, fp.jpg, front.htm, logo.jpg, random.js, 
                     styles.css
-->
   <title>The Ridgewood Herald Tribune</title>
   <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
        function randInt(n) {
            randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*n);
            return randNum;
        }

        function adDescription(n) {
            var descrip = new Array();
            descrip[1]="[AD] Diamond Health Club - For all your Health Club Needs";
            descrip[2]="[AD] Pixal - Quality Digital Equipment and Accessories";
            descrip[3]="[AD] dHome - Quality Geodesic Domes and Homes";
            descrip[4]="[AD] Dunston Retreat Center - get away";
            descrip[5]="[AD] LanGear - Quality Network Solutions for all your Business Needs";

            return descrip[n];
        }

        function adLink(n) {
            var link = new Array();
            link[1]="http://www.diamondhealth.com";
            link[2]="http://www.pixalproducts.com";
            link[3]="http://www.dhome.com";
            link[4]="http://www.dunstonretreats.com";
            link[5]="http://wwww.langearproducts.com";

            return link[n];
        }
   </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="links">
  <h1>Contents</h1>
  <p class="section">Main</p>
  <p class="linksub">
     <a href="#">Home</a><br />
     <a href="#">Subscriptions</a><br />
     <a href="#">Contact Us</a><br />
     <a href="#">News Sources</a><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p class="section">News</p>
  <p class="linksub">
    <a href="#">Local</a><br />
    <a href="#">National</a><br />
    <a href="#">International</a><br />
  </p>

  <p class="section">Sports</p>
  <p class="linksub">
    <a href="#">Baseball</a><br />
    <a href="#">Basketball</a><br />
    <a href="#">Football</a><br />
    <a href="#">Golf</a><br />
    <a href="#">Hockey</a><br />
    <a href="#">Miscellaneous</a><br />
  </p>

  <p class="section">Opinion</p>
  <p class="linksub">
    <a href="#">Editorials</a><br />
    <a href="#">Columnists</a><br />
    <a href="#">Letters</a><br />
  </p>

  <p class="section">Classifieds</p>
  <p class="linksub">
    <a href="#">Employment</a><br />
    <a href="#">For Sale</a><br />
    <a href="#">Personals</a><br />
    <a href="#">Real Estate</a><br />
    <a href="#">Wanted</a><br />
  </p>

  <p class="section">Other</p>
  <p class="linksub">
    <a href="#">Business</a><br />
    <a href="#">Weather</a><br />
    <a href="#">Entertainment</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="ads">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var rNumber = randInt(5); //generate a random integer form 1 to 5
        var rAd = adDescription(rNumber); //description of the random ad
        var rLink = adLink(rNumber); //URL of the random ad

        document.write("<a href='" + rLink + "'>");
        document.write("img src='ad" + rNumber + ".jpg' alt='" + rAd + "' />");
        document.write("</a>");

      </script>
  </div>

  <div id="request"><a href="#">Contact us today to place your ad</a></div>

  <p id="logo"> 
     <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Ridgewood Herald Tribune" />
  </p>

  <p id="fp">
  <img src="fp.jpg" alt="" />
  </p>

  <h2>Park Opens</h2>
  <p id="intro">The <i>Adventure Island</i> theme park opened its doors on 
  Monday near Ridgewood. The park, one of the biggest in New Jersey, drew
  large crowds, but the long lines didn't deter anyone. "I've been watching
  them put up the rides over the last year, it's really exciting to finally
  get inside the gates!" said Ridgewood resident, Denise Brooks.</p>

  <p class="cont"><a href="#">story continues on page 2...</a></p>

  <address id="footer">
  <b>Ridgewood Herald Tribune</b> &nbsp;&#176;&nbsp; 10010 Atwood Ave. 
  &nbsp;&#176;&nbsp; Ridgewood, NJ &nbsp; &nbsp; 07451<br />
  Phone: (201)555-1101 &nbsp;&#176;&nbsp; Fax: (201)555-1102
  </address>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you populating your `Arrays` starting with the 2nd (`[1]`) element, instead of the 1st (`[0]`)?

Comment: Not exactly related, but IE will fall to Quirks mode on this page. In IEs DTD must be placed on the very first line of the file without any preceding characters.

Comment: Starting the arrays with 1 is incorrect/unusual, but because the random number generation returns numbers 1..5 instead of 0..4 the code gets away with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i check the HTML in Firebug this is what i am getting.You are missing "<" on the image tag.

[img src='ad2.jpg' alt='[AD] Pixal - Quality Digital Equipment and Accessories' />](http://www.pixalproducts.com)

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this, little mistakes like this are easily overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML to display the image is missing a leading < sign is this the problem or a typo?

```
    document.write("img src='ad" + rNumber + ".jpg' alt='" + rAd + "' />");
```

should be:

```
    //              <
    document.write("<img src='ad" + rNumber + ".jpg' alt='" + rAd + "' />");
```

Note also that declaring fixed arrays in functions is slightly shady, as every time the functions get called these arrays get reinitialised. The arrays should probably be simply declared and initialised outside the functions.

Answer (score -1):

I just started an ad server for our website, hunt-club.org, and I wanted to share the code for displaying our ads:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><a id="quote"><img id="quoteimg" width=609 height="120"></a><button id="skipad" onclick="window.location.href='https://codeprojects.org/_uLaNvBTx-FcGfHyDjXb0gtobzURizMHlxxylr5Cf3E/ad1skip.html'" class="adskip">X</button>

<style>
  .adskip {
    position: absolute;
    left: 600px;
  }
  </style>
  



  <script src="https://codeprojects.org/_uLaNvBTx-FcGfHyDjXb0gtobzURizMHlxxylr5Cf3E/ad1.js">
    
  </script>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```